# Image pixel colors list, convert from RGBA to BGRA?

Tags: python, list, blender

I have a list of floats which is an image pixel data. Each 4 floats make a RGBA pixel. What would be the most efficient way to convert that list to BGRA format (order) instead?

What I have:

```
[R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A]
```

What I need:

```
[B, G, R, A, B, G, R, A]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grouper recipe from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip_longest
>>> def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

>>> pixels = [70, 140, 210, 0.5, 60, 100, 200, 0.7]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((b,g,r,a) for r,g,b,a in grouper(4, pixels)))
[210, 140, 70, 0.5, 200, 100, 60, 0.7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [v[a if a & 1 else a ^ 2] for a in range(len(v))]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very Pythonic, but <strike>maybe efficient</strike>:

```
final = []
for i in range(len(data)/4):
    final.extend(data[4*i:4*i+3][::-1])
    final.append(data[4*i+3])
```

Edit: if you could modify the list in place, that would be perfect IMHO:

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    data[i:i+3] = data[i:i+3][::-1]
```

Comment: After timing it, this is less efficient than my solution using a list of 80 elements although it is more efficient on a small list. Even so it looks disgusting!

Comment: @jamylak thanks, good to know. And since I can't test right now, what about some more realistic case of ~500k?

Comment: With 100 repeats on 500k, mine runs in `3.24s`, this runs in `8.52s`. Using `xrange` instead of `range` takes it down to `8.19s` and appending instead of using extend with the reverse slice takes `7.38s`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain,izip
L = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
print list(chain(*((C,B,A,D) for A,B,C,D in izip(*[iter(L)]*4))))
```

Comment: The elements in this are not chained together, they remain in the tuples of 4. Also PEP-8 discourages using `l` as a variable name since it can be confused with the number `1`. Use `L` or a better name.